# Why do certain materials of nature ring when struck?

Tags: acoustics

There are a wide range of elements and natural materials that will give off a ringing sound based on the material and the profile of the object is correct, most first think of metals ring best because they vibrate best. I've heard  Metals,glass,jade and many more natural elements ring, but the latest object i've heard ring was a rock and made me start to think there's more behind the ring.

The rock resembled a flattened river rock and was dull grey throughout its surface with no signs of quartz or metallic elements in its structure. The rock was oval and had a large diameter of 1' and a small diameter of 5" and a thickness of 2".

**Question**-
 Is a similar crystalline structure the reason behind the ring?

Comment: Glass doesn't have a crystal structure but it rings just fine. The requirement for a material to have a high mechanical quality factor is that the internal dampening, i.e. the energy dissipation of mechanical excitations, is low.

Comment: @CuriousOne- Glass will form a crystalline structure if heated at 380k  for a 1/2 hr.

Comment: You are welcome to try that experiment in your oven.

Comment: If by structure you mean "defects", then, in some very weak way, yes.

Comment: @CuriousOne- I am 99 percent sure it is the crystalline structure. This theory came to me as intuition,  I  have no knowledge of acoustics or internal structures of certain elements and I just found two separate references stating that the ring comes from the crystalline structure. So I post questions for confirmation .

Comment: No matter how sure you are, glass is a perfect counterexample. So is air, by the way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In a way, the 'similar crystal structure' IS responsible for ringing.  This is because homogeneous solids can transmit sound over long distances, and one can excite resonances of the entire solid object, often audible.  We cannot hear the ultrasonic ringing sound of a very small object, because the resonances are all above the frequency sensitivity range of our ears.   We can hear huge bells ring, though, even if the fundamental resonance is too low in pitch, because many integer multiples of that fundamental frequency are audible resonances.

Resonance, repeating oscillation, is what we call 'ringing', and it decays after a while: it might take seconds for a large bell, milliseconds for a small one.

A sound wave, a phonon, is randomized by scattering and is thermalized by 'umklapp processes'; some materials with irregular microstructure, like granite (with grains of multiple different materials) scatter phonons which removes energy from the resonance, other materials have very high defect counts, and those defects can suck energy from phonons by widening gaps, or closing them.   There is a plastic material  that absorbs very little energy, and balls from this material are 'superballs', very bouncy.  Other plastics that look the same are completely dead (if you throw an 'infraball' hard, at a concrete floor, it'll bounce an
inch or two), presumably because of high rate of umklapp processes.  Before the sound of the impact travels to the other side of the infraball, reflects, and returns, most of the energy is transformed to heat.  So, no bounce.